# Pointer to vector data fails

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class that manipulates a block of memory.

```
class cPacket {
public:
cPacket( 
    : vBuffer( 96000 )
{
#ifdef USE_VECTOR
    myPacketBuffer = vBuffer.data();
#else
    myPacketBuffer = aPacketBuffer;

}

...

protected:
unsigned char * myPacketBuffer;
std::vector< unsigned char > vBuffer;
unsigned char aPacketBuffer[ 96000 ];
};
```

In the code, only the myPacketBuffer pointer is used to access the 96000 byte memory block

Using the array, everything works perfectly.

Using the vector, all unit tests work, but the production application runs for a while, then crashes mysteriously deep in the system code, apparently something to do with allocating memory

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

[image]

Using a vector will be much more convenient - I can allocate smaller memory blocks if the maximum is not needed.

What is the difference between using an array and vector, that might be causing the crashes when the vector is used.

Comment: Do you pass around `cPacket` objects by value? Like passing as argument to a function or returning an object from a function? Do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: Stack trace looks corrupt. Does your class have a proper copy constructor / copy assignment operator? If not, make sure to delete those so it isn't accidentally copied

Comment: Are you inserting all data into the vector at once?  If not, keep in mind that iterators and pointers into a vector are invalidated if the vector's internal capacity changes.

Comment: @Yexo Deleting the copy constructor made no difference.  However, I think that this might well be the problem - the copy will be pointing to the buffer belonging to the original and when that is deleted all hell will break loose.

Comment: also running off the end of a vector vs the local buffer will clobber different memory, resulting in different undefined behavior. Are you sure you are not running off the end (note that you are side stepping the vectors bounds checks by using data())

Comment: @pm100 That is a reasonable concern.  However, I have been using the array version heavily for over a year without a single problem, so I do not think that is the problem

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: @Yexo  Deleting the copy assignment operator did - the program no longer compiled.  Writing an assignment operator which points to its own buffer fixed the crashes.  Now I have to decide if using a vector is worth the trouble of maintaining user defined constructors and assignments.  Anyhow, if you post an answer I will accept it.